# Kibana : Date format error when filtering by date

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Working on the ELK stack, i am getting shards errors when trying to filter by date value :

```
{
  "took": 2305,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 373,
    "successful": 367,
    "skipped": 367,
    "failed": 6,
    "failures": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "covid19_api_pubmed_1987",
        "node": "AvkWzN91S3ag_b7Alq5syw",
        "reason": {
          "type": "query_shard_exception",
          "reason": "failed to create query: failed to parse date field [1988-01-25T00:00:00.000Z] with format [yyyy-MM-dd]: [failed to parse date field [1988-01-25T00:00:00.000Z] with format [yyyy-MM-dd]]",
          "index_uuid": "PAbizUHTSaKN5YgCD3-qaQ",
          "index": "covid19_api_pubmed_1987",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "parse_exception",
            "reason": "failed to parse date field [1988-01-25T00:00:00.000Z] with format [yyyy-MM-dd]: [failed to parse date field [1988-01-25T00:00:00.000Z] with format [yyyy-MM-dd]]",
            "caused_by": {
              "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
              "reason": "failed to parse date field [1988-01-25T00:00:00.000Z] with format [yyyy-MM-dd]",
              "caused_by": {
                "type": "date_time_parse_exception",
                "reason": "date_time_parse_exception: Text '1988-01-25T00:00:00.000Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

I tried to investigate on the problem, this is what I have got so far :

- Mappings for all indices are correct (i.e "type" : "date" and "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd")
- Searched for all documents with _ignored via

```
 "query": {
       "exists": {
         "field": "_ignored"
       }
     }
```

And got no errors returned.

- Found a [related github issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/93401) with a similar problem, that is still open. Yet i feel like if it was a global Kibana problem, more people should be talking about it ? idk

If anyone has a clue, feel free !

Comment: where do you get this error?

Comment: https://ibb.co/QKyFjVP I got some "shards errors" on the bottom right when trying to add a date as a filter (from the little + button in a document table)